# Python Read strings from file

Tags: python, string, list, directory

Unfortunately I have the problem that I can not read strings from files, the part of the code would be:

```
names = ["Johnatan", "Jackson"]
```

I tried it with this =
`open("./names.txt", "r")`
instead of (code above)- list of names, but unfortunately this does not work, if I query it without the file it works without problems.

I would be very happy if someone could help me and tell me exactly where the problem is.

Comment: can u send how your file contains the data?

Comment: In the Textfile i use "Johnatan", "Jackson", "Maria"

Comment: I hope its comma-separated right?

Comment: yea i done that

Comment: Could you explain "does not work"? Do you get any error? Could you show the code that doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

```
f = open('./names.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8')
words_string = f.readlines()
words = words_string.split(',')

print(words)
```

I hope it helps.. As your file contains all the words with comma-separated using **readlines** we get all the lines in the file as a single string and then simply split the string using **.split(',')**. This results in the list of words that you need.

Answer (score 0):

try read the data in the file like this:

```
with open(file_path, "r") as f:
    data = f.readlines()
```

data = ['maria, Johnatan, Jackson']

inside data is the list of name. you can parse it using `split(",")`

Answer (score 0):

you can split in lines if you have in the file, `Johnatan,Jackson,Maria`
doing:

```
with open("./names.txt", "r", encoding='utf-8') as fp:
    content = fp.read()
    names = content.split(",")
```

you can also do:

```
names = open("./names.txt", "r", encoding='utf-8').read().split(",")
```

if you want it to be oneliner,